# When I put a scanf inside of a switch case with type char it skips it entirely why?

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, scanf

When I put a scanf inside of a switch case with type char it skips it entirely why? It works if I change the type to an int or a float or any other type but with a char it just skips over it. I'm just using this code as an example of the problem im facing. I'm trying to use a scanf inside of a case to get a char to use as selection for a sub switch statement. If it matters.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h.>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")

main(){
    char choice;
    char switchChoice;

    printf("choose A");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice){
    case 'A':
        printf("see if this works");
        scanf("%c", &switchChoice);
        printf("%c", switchChoice);
        PAUSE;

    }//end switch


}// END MAIN
```

Comment: did you try to flush input before 2nd `scanf` call?

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf(" %c", &switchChoice);
       ^ put a space before %c in scanf
```

Due to previous `scanf` `\n` remains in `stdin` and second `scanf` stores that in your variable and doesn't wait for input .

Answer (score 1):

just **clear input buffer after first scanf**, it not reads `\n` so buffer is not clean for second read.
and **always check for errors**:

```
if (scanf("%c%*c", &choice) != 1) return 1;
```

you may use `choice = getch();` to read just one char without Enter `\n` or 
use `scanf("%c%*c", &choice);` to read `\n`  or clear input buffer.

working sample code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h.>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")

main(){
    char choice;
    char switchChoice;

    printf("choose A");
//  scanf("%c%*c", &choice);
    choice = getch();

    switch (choice){
    case 'A':
        printf("see if this works");
        scanf("%c", &switchChoice);
        printf("%c", switchChoice);
        PAUSE;

    }//end switch

}// END MAIN
```

another working sample code :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h.>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")

main(){
    char choice;
    char switchChoice;

    printf("choose A");
    if (scanf("%c%*c", &choice) != 1) return 1;
    switch (choice){
    case 'A':
        printf("see if this works");
        scanf("%c", &switchChoice);
        printf("%c", switchChoice);
        PAUSE;
    }//end switch
}// END MAIN
```

see: [How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)